# Boost Exception Handling with Boost ASIO

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I was going over [this](http://www.gamedev.net/blog/950/entry-2249317-a-guide-to-getting-started-with-boostasio/?pg=6) example 5a - it covers exception handling with boost asio
The code for the example is pasted here from that link for quick reference

```
boost::mutex global_stream_lock;

void WorkerThread( boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service )
{
    ....

    try
    {
        io_service->run();
    }
    catch( std::exception & ex )
    {
        ....
    }

}

void RaiseAnException( boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service )
{
    io_service->post( boost::bind( &RaiseAnException, io_service ) );

    throw( std::runtime_error( "Oops!" ) );
}

int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service > io_service(
        new boost::asio::io_service
        );
    boost::shared_ptr< boost::asio::io_service::work > work(
        new boost::asio::io_service::work( *io_service )
        );


    boost::thread_group worker_threads;
    for( int x = 0; x < 2; ++x )
    {
        worker_threads.create_thread( boost::bind( &WorkerThread, io_service ) );
    }

    io_service->post( boost::bind( &RaiseAnException, io_service ) );

    worker_threads.join_all();

    return 0;
}
```

My question is why isnt the exception caught here ? Why did the author have to do **both mechansims `error code` and `try-catch` to catch an exception like this**

```
try
        {
            boost::system::error_code ec;
            io_service->run( ec );
            if( ec )
            {
                ....
            }
            break;
        }
        catch( std::exception & ex )
        {
            ....
        }
```

I also dont understand what the author means by saying

> To further clarify once again if we are using the io_service for user
>   work, we have to use exception handling if the work can generate
>   exceptions. If we are using the io_service for boost::asio functions
>   only, then we can use exception handling or the error variable as
>   either will do. If we are using the io_service for both boost::asio
>   functions and user work, then we can either use both methods or just
>   the exception handling method, but not only the error variable if the
>   work can generate an exception. That should be pretty straightforward
>   to follow.

I would appreciate it if someone could clarify this

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation you quote is somewhat misleading.

Actually, `io_service` propagates any exceptions that escape from completion handlers, so it doesn't matter whether we use it for "user work" or for "asio functions" - in any case we might want to handle exceptions escaping from `io_service::run` (not only `std::exception`!).
Consider the following sample:

```
void my_handler(const error_code&)
{
  // this exception will escape from io_service::run()!
  throw 0;
}

void setup_timer()
{
  deadline_timer_.expires_from_now(seconds(5));
  deadline_timer_.async_wait(my_handler);
}
```

The difference between `io_service::run(error_code &ec)` and `io_service::run()` is that the latter deliberately *throws* an exception, if `ec` implies error. Quoting from `io_service.ipp`:

```
std::size_t io_service::run()
{
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  std::size_t s = impl_.run(ec);
  boost::asio::detail::throw_error(ec);
  return s;
}
```

So, the bottom line is that it would be enough to use the throwing overload (and, optionally, multiple `catch` handlers to distinguish between exception types).